If $I$ is generated by a regular sequence mod $J$, then $I\cap J = IJ$
Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I, J$ ideals. Let $I$ be generated by elements that form a regular sequence mod $J$. I have already proven the following, which I am asked to use:
$$Tor_1(R/I, R/J) = (I\cap J)/IJ$$
I was thinking of constructing a short exact sequence from which I could obtain a long exact sequence after tensoring with $R/J$. Something like $$0\to (x_n)\to R/(x_1,...,x_{n-1})\to R/I\to 0$$
where $I=(x_1,...,x_n)$. Normally tensoring does not preserve exactness, but maybe because $x_1,...,x_n$ form a regular sequence mod $J$ we still get the surjectivity for the map $R/J\otimes R/(x_1,...,x_{n-1})\to R/J\otimes R/I$ which would mean $Tor_1(R/I,R/J)=0$ and by the fact I already proved this would mean $I\cap J= IJ$. However, I do not feel confident about this approach. Is there any better way to approach this problem? Thank you.
